# UWP Equivalent of MultiDataTrigger in WPF

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want my Button enabled only when both my CheckBox checked. But this code is not working. Button is always enabled.
I think a `MultiDataTrigger` in WPF can do this, but in UWP I don't have `MultiDataTrigger`.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Condition1">
<CheckBox x:Name="Condition2">

<Button x:Name="LoginBtn" Click="LoginBtn_Click" Content="Login">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=Condition1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding LoginBtn}" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=Condition2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding LoginBtn}" PropertyName="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
        <Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=LoginBtn, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
            <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Gray"/>
        </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using MVVM, you could use CanExecute to enable and disable the button

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `DataTriggerBehavior` is unlike the `DataTrigger` in WPF, which won't restore the target property to default if condition is not met.

So, finally I have found a walkaround in a programmatic way.

```
private bool? condition1
{
    get { return Condition1.IsChecked; }
    set
    {
        Condition1.IsChecked = value;
        if ((value ?? false) && (condition2 ?? false)) LoginBtn.IsEnabled = true;
        else LoginBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
private bool? condition2
{
    get { return Condition2.IsChecked; }
    set
    {
        Condition2.IsChecked = value;
        if ((value ?? false) && (condition1 ?? false)) LoginBtn.IsEnabled = true;
        else LoginBtn.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="Condition1" IsChecked="{x:Bind condition1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<CheckBox x:Name="Condition2" IsChecked="{x:Bind condition1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

For the button color

```
<Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=LoginBtn, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
    <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Gray"/>
</Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
<Core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=LoginBtn, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
    <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="White"/>
</Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
```

Also set the button default `IsEnable=False`

I think this can be achieved by `CompositeStateTrigger` in a vsm.
**Looking forward to better solution!**